# Using MySQL for Excel - one particular table from a database won't import, all other tables work fine

Tags: mysql, sql, database, excel

I just installed MySQL For Excel and have successfully connected to my database.

I have been trying to import various tables by selecting the table name and clicking "Import MySQL Data". All the tables have imported just fine except for ONE table.

I do know that this particular problem table was created from scratch by me awhile back to add a new product to our website. Is there some sort of setting that the table structure has to have within myPHPAdmin to allow it to be imported?

Thanks.

Comment: The error I get is: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.All the other tables, the import preview comes up immediately. The problem table is a lot smaller than the other tables that have successfully been imported.

Comment: What are the datatypes for all the columns in the table?  Are there any "exotic" columns such as BLOBS or LONGTEXT?  LONGTEXT can store 4,294,967,295 bytes but Excel can only store 32,767 characters in a cell (sorry for not converting the two, but I think Excel might count Unicode as a character and not by the bytes, so they're not exactly one-to-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug to mySQL and they actually fixed it!! The full link to the bug submission and their back and forth can be found here: http://bugs.mysql.com/?id=71004&edit=2